# Install Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, oracle11g, archlinux

Newbie here,Kindly bear with me. 
I would like to install **Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2**  in **Arch Linux**.

I've downloaded the **oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip** then unzipped it to **/home/user/Downloads/Disk1**. In that folder there is **oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm** file.

As per this [Oracle Installation manual in Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Oracle) there are several method. I would like to follow **Install method 2 - AUR** method as I guess its bit easy than other(Actually I don't understand other method much and have confusions).

But when I try to install `oracle` from **AUR**, I found this problem: **error: target not found: oracle**. I think that package is no more available.

How can I proceed futher? As a learner it would be helpful for me if steps are bit explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

AUR package is named "oracle-xe", not "oracle". 
You should download snapshot from

https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/oracle-xe/

and uncompress it. Then step into **oracle-xe** directory and type

**makepkg -s**

But I vote for installing qemu and centos minimal, then Oracle inside it. Oracle is so painful to install even in supported distribs.
Also you will pollute your Arch with unnecessary symlinks and applications.